# VBScript runtime error: Object required (Windows 2003)

Tags: vbscript

Trying to return string from Function results in **Object required** error.
Running this code on Windows 2003. Note: on w2k3, `Win32_OperatingSystem` does
not support the `=@` singleton which is why we're using `For Each ... / Exit Function`

```
Function GetLocalTime()
    Dim wmi, itm
    Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2")
    For Each itm in wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem")
        ' NEXT LINE THROWS 'Object required' error
        GetLocalTime = itm.LocalDateTime
        Exit Function
    Next
End Function

Dim started : Set started = GetLocalTime
WScript.Echo "started " & started
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. The error message reported as occurring within the body of the `GetLocalTime()` function, but the error was actually from the call. Needed to remove `Set`.  Here is corrected code:

```
Function GetLocalTime()
    Dim wmi, itm
    Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2")
    For Each itm in wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem")
        GetLocalTime = itm.LocalDateTime
        Exit Function
    Next
End Function

Dim started : started = GetLocalTime  ' <-- CHANGED LINE
WScript.Echo "started " & started
```